# jQuery How to remove specific hidden fields

Tags: javascript, jquery

Am trying to remove all input hidden fields which doesnt belong to `class="MultiFiles"` using jQuery

Below are my sample hidden input fields

```
<input value="I48rVUwTtrjk" name="UNIQUE_TOKEN" type="hidden">
<input value="151" name="context" type="hidden">
<input type="hidden"  name="isMultiOperation" value="true">
<input type="hidden" class="MultiFiles" name="instance_submittedFile.name" value="">
<input type="hidden" class="MultiFiles" name="instance_submittedFile.fileData.id" value="">
```

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: Please provide the code that you have written to try to solve the problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use this :

```
$('input[type=hidden]').not('.MultiFiles').remove();
```

[.not() Jquery](http://shorthug.com/8a5ad26)

Comment: what is the opposite of 'not'. like if I only want to remove MultiFiles within all hidden fields. and MultiFiles is also available as 'not hidden' input field.

Answer (score 1):

Use `$("#container input[type='hidden']:not(.MultiFiles)").remove();`

Answer (score 1):

```
$('input[type=hidden]:not(.MultiFiles)').remove();
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try this

```
$("input[class!='MultiFiles']").remove();
```

Comment: This removes all input fields that does not have class MultiFiles

Comment: While this may work in this exact example, if the inputs had any additional classes, the inputs would all be removed.

Comment: While I agree with both of you, i literally just looked at the example.